# I choosed USD Website but showing a "Your credit card will be charged for..."

Tags: currency

I successfully created 2 website (US and CA). Everything works fine and the currency looks good. I configure everything properly. However when I was testing the US website (all US Dollar) in the checkout page. I see a message below the grand total "Your credit card will be charged for   CA$ 13.00.
When I go to my admin, everything is based on a conversion from CAD to US$. Is this normal?
I also see it on my order confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

1. check your base currency may be $CA
2. What is the extension you are using for payment?? Than can also change your base currency